# How to Normalize a function in python?

Tags: function, matplotlib, normalization, wave, uninitialized-constant

I'm new to python. Can anyone help me about the following...

I want to plot a wave function. When entering the wave function formula, should I write it's normalization constant too? Or can the Python normalize it by writting a code (for example ".unit()")?

I think there is no need to write normalization constant separately. If it is true, What is the command for this?

Comment: You can have different definitions of _normalization_, do you think that Python should know what is your choice?

Comment: That's right. I thought normalization has the same concept for example in math and physics. I mean in this question was normalization process in Physics for wave functions. I'm sorry my question wasn't clear.